# Java script : How to find setInterval function is now running or timedout?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

In my project I use two setInterval functions, One function is running all time. The second function is start and stop dynamically according to keyboard input. How to find state(Running or Timeout) of second setInterval funcion?

```
    setInterval(function()
            {
            if(//want to check state of seInterval Function fire)
                      {
                       //somecode
                      }
            },300);
  var fire=setInterval(function()
            {
                     // some code
            },300);
```

Comment: if you post a code it's better.. anyway define always setinterval & settimeout ... var myTimer=setTimeout(func,500);clearTimeout(myTimer)

Comment: I can't find where you're stopping of second function (ie., **clearInterval**)

Comment: According to keyboard input it start and stop.(Other part of of code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better add a **`boolean`** variable **`isRunning`** to the methods in setInterval.  Toggle the value according to it.  Using the value you can track the status.

Based on the code you have posted:

```
isFirstInstanceRunning =true;
isSecondInstanceRunning = false;
setInterval(function() {
    //want to check state of seInterval Function fire
    if(isFirstInstanceRunning){
        //somecode
    }
},300);

//--- Pass a boolean parameter as "true" onKeypress     
function startSecondInstance(toCheck) {     
    var fire=setInterval(function() {
        //want to check state of seInterval Function fire
        if(toCheck){
            //somecode
        }
    },300);
}

//---Similarly when you stop the second method
function stopSecondInstance() {
    clearInterval(fire);
    isSecondInstanceRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Apparently we think alike on variable names :D +1

Comment: @tymeJV First time for me in SO.  Even the **variable name** is alike(same pinch) :)  +1 for showing example code.

Comment: Is there any default methode to do it? For example, here variable fire store the value, how many time the setInterval function run.   Thank you :) . Soory for bad english.

Comment: @mridul I think there is no default method.  If you want to find the count(no. of times the fire being called) then you need to **add a new variable inside `setInterval` of fire and increment it gracefully**.  Hope that make sense.

Answer (score 2):

No, not directly, however you could set a variable to check on periodically to see if it's running:

```
var isRunning = false;

//Start it
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    //yada yada function stuff
    isRunning = true;
}, 3000);

//Check it
if (isRunning) console.log("Running!");

//Stop it
clearInterval(timer);
isRunning = false;
```